# using selenium does not return content

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Help me understand this when trying to get the contents for https://www.sayurbox.com/ or https://segari.id/products does not return any content.

Here is my code

!pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

# setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

# set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# Access a URL (replace with your URL)
url = "https://segari.id/p/timun-lalap"  # Make sure to include the protocol (https://)
driver.get(url)

# Get the page content or perform other actions as needed
page_content = driver.page_source
print(page_content)

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Does it have something to do with https://www.sayurbox.com/confirmation?redirectTo=%2F
the first thing a form that shows up.

I am trying to understand why this is happening? Can someone help me with this.
The content returned is

## 403 ERROR

Comment: If a pop-up shows up when a page loads, you will not be able to see the content. You need to handle that first and then access the page.

Comment: first run without `'--headless'` to see what you get in browser. Maybe there will be message or Captcha.

Comment: maybe server has problem and admins have to repair it. And then you can't to fix it

Comment: there is supposed to be a form to click a button to redirect. but selenium does not detect the form

Comment: headless returns 403